# how to divide section HTML (BOOTSTRAP)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need to divide my section horizontally in 3 parts to place a IMG in each part (centered)
and write some text down each.
should look like:

border-------------img---------------------img-----------------img-------------------border

Thanks for reading this c:

pd: english is not my first lenguague, so if can write as simple as possible i will appreciate it.
pd2: im new on HTML

so here is my example code:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <article class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Welcome to my first HTML website</h2>
            <p>This is a lot of text</p>
        </article>  
        <section class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="">
                    <img src="images/icon-mantencion.png"  width="100" height="100">
                    <img src="images/icono-reparacion.png"  width="100" height="100">
                    <img src="images/icon-moderniza.png"  width="100" height="100">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>  
    </section>
</div>
```

the problem in my code: i wasnt writing that "section" was a single horizontally space, and then diving each IMG like "class=col-lg-4". so (before) when i wrote in each img class="col-lg-4" the webpage thought that each img was a single horizontal space. 
then should look like this:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="images/icon-mantencion.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="images/icono-reparacion.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="images/icon-moderniza.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div>                
        </div>
```

Comment: `<div class="cols-md-4">place your text and image here</div><div class="cols-md-4">place your text and image here</div><div class="cols-md-4">place your text and image here</div>`

Comment: add your code jsfiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani there is an inbuilt editor in stackoverflow in case you didn't knew

Comment: by centered, you mean vertically..? horizontally..? both..? Did you read the bootstrap documentation about their grid system..? What is the problem you're facing with it..?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <article class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Welcome to my first HTML website</h2>
            <p>This is a lot of text</p>
        </article>  
        <section class="row">
              <div class="cols-md-4">
                 <img src="images/icon-mantencion.png"  width="100" height="100">
              </div>
              <div class="cols-md-4">
                 <img src="images/icono-reparacion.png"  width="100" height="100">
              </div>
              <div class="cols-md-4">
                 <img src="images/icon-moderniza.png"  width="100" height="100">
              </div>  
        </section>  
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `<div class="">`..?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap  **class="col-xs-12"** means a single block that contains 12 equal blocks.

As per your requirement, you want to create three equal blocks, so divide 12 blocks into 3 equal blocks with **class="col-xs-4"**

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <article class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Welcome to my first HTML website</h2>
            <p>This is a lot of text</p>
        </article>  
        <section class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="images/icon-mantencion.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="images/icono-reparacion.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="images/icon-moderniza.png"  width="100" height="100"> </div> 
        </section>  
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12">` is useless in this case. You can directly split the `.row` into 3 columns

Comment: im love with you, thank you very much i dont know how i didnt think that before...

Comment: @AbhishekSharma i edited the post explaining my mistake and how to fix it c: ty

Comment: currently how it looks like? could you please share link to check.